# how add authentication in a middleware or pre-route?

Tags: clojure, middleware, noir

how to carry out an authentication process for each request sent. The problem i'm currently facing is i'm not able access user data which is sent as a request param. here is what i have tried

```
(pre-route[:any "/mainpage/*"] {:keys[data]}
 (when (not(contains? data "userid"))
   //false response
  )
)
```

and the middleware

```
(defn for-auth [handler]

  (fn [req]
    (if (contains? (:body (:params req)))
      (handler req)
      (handler (assoc req :body {})
    )
   )
)
```

and i add the middlware too. but neither of them work.. Any idea to access user params..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what i have done and it solves my problem..

```
(pre-route [:any "/mainroute/*"] {{:keys [jsondata]}:params}
  (let [data (httputil/parse-json-data jsondata)]

  (cond
    (not (true? valid_req)) "false"
    (not (true? version_check)) "false"
    (not (true? user_valid)) "false"
    )
   )
  )
```

here i have parsed my json data in middleware and added it to "params" with key name :jsondata..
 it works perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

Sandy

Are you using wrap params?

..
(:use [ring.middleware params])

(def app
  (-> (handler/site main-routes)
      (wrap-base-url)
      (wrap-params)))